# if the "Embedded Google assistant SDK" has been released?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assist-api, google-assistant-sdk

I'd like to know if the "Embedded Google assistant SDK" has been released? I saw https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/, the Conversation Actions and Direct Actions are here, but I can't find the document about "Google assistant SDK", so can someone tell me the status?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the actions SDK has been released.

The SDK for embedding google assistant - the equivelent of Amazon's 'alexa voice service' - has not been released.

Comment: thank you. I'm waiting for the SDK to do things like "Alexa voice service". so, just waiting it.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually release about 2-3 weeks ago. You can find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/)